# If I refresh or click a button to go to a link, link works, but if I type the URL, it does not

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, navbar

Right now, I have a very data-intensive set of HTML and JS documents that are all connected through a Nav-Bar. One of the pages works only if I go to the page via Navbar, and it loads fine. If I refresh the page, it also continues to work exactly how I wanted it to.

However, when I copy the exact same URL which is on the page when I load it, and try going directly to the website via URL, the page doesn't load all the JSON files, etc. that it needs to. I find this odd because in all 3 cases, I am accessing the same HTML document, but I'm not sure why using the link does not work.

Edit: To reiterate, when I type in the link, the main CSS, etc. still works, the site design is still there, however, for some reason, the JS doesn't load all of the JSON files and content that is necessary.

Comment: Are your events on the button clicks handling the loading of the data in some way that the pageload event is not?

Comment: @PWilliams0530 I don't believe so. All the necessary loading is done on pageload, which involves some variables present within the URL itself and JSON files as mentioned. All the button click does is give an "href" to this other page. 

In computer terms, is there a difference between refreshing a page and just typing the URL again?